# How to access libraries installed via NPM when running a Firebase app using 'firebase serve'?

Tags: firebase, npm

This is my **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

    <link type="text/css" href="node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.css">
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.3.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.3.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.3.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.3.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
    <script defer src="scripts/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...Something...
    <script src="node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.js"></script>
    <script>mdc.autoInit()</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Neither the stylesheet in line 7 or the script inside `<body>` are loaded.

My project structure is as follows. I included only the relevant files and directories. **public** is the public directory as set up in **firebase.json**. I don't want to keep all my project in the project root directory.

```
Project
|-node_modules
|-public
| |-index.html
| |-...
|
|-firebase.json
|-...
```

My **firebase.json** file:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase hosting doesn't include any server-side installation or package management. So you'll need to upload the dependencies as part of the static assets during a deploy.

Locally, you'll probably want to place those within the public folder (the deployed content) or use a Gulp/Grunt task to copy them there.